# Change specific string in href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

thanks for taking your time to help me!

I want to remove the special link example "/siteurl/" from href on each li in this special div #nav

How it is now:

```
<div id="nav" class="menu">
   <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="/siteurl/#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="/siteurl/#services">Services</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

I need to be like this:

```
<div id="nav" class="menu">
   <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here's the snippet](http://jsbin.com/AyeFIxU/6/edit)

and the code (should be self explaining)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //the <li> > <a>'s of the menu
  $('#nav li a').each(function(){
    //what we are looking fore
   var search = '/siteurl/';
    //the current url
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    //check if url begins with pattern
    if(href.indexOf(search) === 0){
      //now remove it
      href = href.substr(search.length);
      //and update the attribute
      $(this).attr('href', href);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$('#nav li a').each()`?

Comment: Thank you very much :) I really appreciate your time and your help. 

I am not very familiar with jquery/javascript

Comment: yeah... thats a good point @ComFreek. I updated it

Comment: regex can make it sorter though. 
this.href=this.href.replace(/^\/siteurl\//,""); It will only replace if it start with /siteurl/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this code should do it:

```
var cutLen = "/siteurl/".length;

$("li a").each(function() {
  this.href = this.href.substr(cutLen);
});
```

Also, you are not allowed to post **questions without showing any attempts** here. We **do not write code** for you.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yeah, but only because the code is so short and *fascinating* (imagine the world before `querySelectorAll`) :) gp: exactly. I like coding (jQuery).

Comment: Can't resist I know. Guilty meself.

Answer (score 1):

A simple string replace method can help you

```
$(".menu a").each(function() {
  this.href = this.href.replace(/\/siteurl\//,"");
});
```

Comment: Fails for `/siteurl/siteurl/#home`. It would be better if you cut the string at the beginning.

Comment: well that's not his case , he mean complete site url on first there I think,  length will also differ if it is /siteurl/siteurl/

Comment: @ComFreek Plus there is no global identifier on regex, so it will do same as your length one is doing. If he want to remove all occurrence he can put g on last of regex.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong (forgot that replace() doesn't automatically replaces all occurrences).